# Android Widget: get position in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget, android-appwidget, remoteview

In a widget, I have a RemoteViews that has a ListView.  I want to get the current position that the user is at in the ListView.  How would I do that?
Is there anything like getFirstVisiblePosition() or getLastVisiblePosition() in RemoteViews?  (I haven't seen anything like that so far.)  Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to get the position by calling getFirstVisiblePosition() on the listView?  I haven't worked with RemoteViews but if you can't access the listView directly it sounds like you could create a public method in your custom RemoteView to return that value.

Comment: No, sadly that is not possible.  AppWidgets are severely limited.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to get current item of list view.
You can get it in few ways mentioned below:

```
     listview.getSelectedItem();
     listview.getSelectedItemPosition();
     listview.getSelectedView();
     listview.getSelectedItemId();
```

Comment: unfortunately his referring to remoteviews